# Show different number of images in different resolutions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

I have to show on my website *5 images all in one row* and they will be resized using media queries so they can fit in the screen. My problem is that for ex. *in an iPhone 5S I need to show only 3 images* not 5 because is a small screen. In iPad and in devices with a larger screen I need to show 5. So which is the best way to achieve this? Should I get the screen size via JavaScript and pass that size to my server to decide how many images should I get from the database or is there another way to do this? I don't want to use an extra mobile site.

The problem is not only the visual side. Those images need to be updated every X seconds so I need to fetch a different number of images from the database based on the screen.

Thanks

Comment: is css3 @media an option?

Comment: css mediaqueries are exactly what you're looking for. this site has pretty good reference about it: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: The problem is not only the visual side. Those images need to be updated every X seconds so I need to fetch a different number of images from the database based on the screen.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Without that, this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect the window size using JQuery like this:

```
$(window).width()
$(window).height()
```

If you don't like to use JQuery, you can do it simply with JavaScript:

```
window.screen.availHeight
window.screen.availWidth
```

Then you could pass these values to your server and decide which images to load.